# Two rotations in $\mathbb R^3$ by irrational angle generate free group $F_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, euclidean-geometry, free-groups

Let $A,B\in $ SO$(3)$ so that $A, B$ are rotations by an angle $\theta\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ about the $z$-axis and $x$-axis, respectively. I want to prove that the group $\langle A, B\rangle$ is isomorphic to $F_2$, the free group on $2$ generators.

It suffices to show that no word in the letters $A, A^{-1}, B, B^{-1}$ has a nontrivial relation (i.e., other than something like $AA^{-1}=e)$.
And in principle an induction argument on the number of letters should work for this, but I have not been able to produce a valid one.

Could someone please help with the proof?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that this is true (regardless of the angle)?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Well, I have seen proofs that there is $\textit{some}$ embedding of $F_2$ into SO$(3)$, but the sort-of generalization I am asking for is based on a lecture given by a professor I had, who said one can show it.

Comment: I do not think this is true. What is true is that for almost all irrational angles $\theta$ the group is free, while (I think) for some irrational angles already $AB$ has finite order. The latter hinges on the following number theory question: Is there $\alpha$, an irrational multiple of $\pi$,   and a rational multiple of $\pi$, call it $\beta$, such that $\cos(\beta)= \cos^2(\alpha)$.